# Failure installing `linux-cloud-tools-common` on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get, certbot

I'm trying to [set up Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutrusty-apache) on an Ubuntu machine but getting the following error when trying to run `apt-get install software-properties-common`:

```
Setting up linux-cloud-tools-common (3.13.0-46.77) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript hv-kvp-daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package linux-cloud-tools-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-cloud-tools-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this blog post](https://infi.nl/nieuws/apt-upgrade-returned-an-error-for-package-linux-cloud-tools-common/), the installation is failing because it fails to find the file `/usr/sbin/hv_kvp_daemon`. You can create a symlink to fix the issue. Run the following command to find this file with a version suffix:

```
 ls /usr/sbin/hv_kvp_daemon_*
```

On my machine, this returned `/usr/sbin/hv_kvp_daemon_3.2.0-58-virtual`, so I then created the following symlink:

```
sudo ln /usr/sbin/hv_kvp_daemon_3.2.0-58-virtual /usr/sbin/hv_kvp_daemon
```

When I re-ran `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`, installation succeeded.